# Dynamic line wrapping in the GNOME Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can you get the lines in the GNOME Terminal to wrap dynamically when you resize the window?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the time the question was asked, this was not possible in Gnome Terminal. However, [a fix was committed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336238) in late 2013. This change didn't make it into Ubuntu 14.04, but it should be part of Ubuntu 14.10.

According to [the issue on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/298385), you can have this feature today by enabling the Gnome-team PPA. You can activate the Gnome-team Staging PPA (staging required to get latest version) by doing the following

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Update your sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Re-install gnome-terminal to get latest version

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Check so you have version 3.13 or later (as of 10 September, should be 3.13.1)

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.12.1
```

Comment: I just installed the Gnome-team PPA, updated, now I have Gnome Terminal 3.10.2.  No dynamic line wrapping.  So...?

Comment: @notfed You'll probably need 3.12, which is available for Ubuntu 14.04 in the `staging` ppa. Try (at your own risk) `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`

Comment: Just tried adding the "normal" ```ppa:gnome3-team:gnome3``` ppa, got a version that was 3.10. After adding ```ppa:gnome3-team:gnome3-staging``` I got the correct version 3.13.1, so I can confirm this is working.

Comment: It's the version number of VTE that really matters. The feature appeared in vte-0.36 (correspondingly, `echo $VTE_VERSION` should report at least 3600).

Comment: I now have `GNOME Terminal 3.12.3` on Ubuntu 14.04 using this method, and reflowing works.

Answer (score 11):

The default Gnome Terminal doesnt allow you to do this - however, if whilst in the terminal you type `screen` - it will run the terminal in a terminal emulator which does resize correctly.

For example - here is my home folder whilst running `ls -l`

[image]

and here is the same screen resized horizontally

[image]

**Starting Gnome-Terminal automatically with Screen**

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

then edit the gnome-terminal.desktop file and change the Exec command line to:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x screen -q
```

Comment: After installing the package - `sudo apt-get install screen` - it does the line wrapping, but running `screen` every time for that purpose is not really unintrusive. Let's see what other workarounds are there.

Comment: very true- have updated with a further suggestion.

Comment: There's a topic about [gnome-terminal + GNU screen integration](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeTerminal/ScreenIntegration) and a [bug report](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeTerminal/ScreenIntegration) but no one is working on it. Still, GNU screen looks like the way to go for dynamic line wrapping.

Comment: You made my day! It works like a charm. Now I just need to look for something similar for the Win terminal. (However, that's so extremely dumb that I think it's impossible.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't start Gnome-Terminal automatically with Screen with the method you described in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Just one more issue: now scrolling is a chore. :( Maybe worse than not having the reflow.

Comment: @allprog - this answer was written in 2011.  Since then, byobu have effectively taken over development of screen since it has been fully integrated into byobu (it inherits much of byobu characteristics). Thus you'll need to learn new keystokes.  For example to scroll you need to go into "copy mode" - ctrl + a + esc.  then use page up or page down.

Comment: For similar reasons I'm not fond of emacs and vim. Shift + up or using the "cat food" just works better for me. I may need to grow up, I know.

Comment: Scrolling can be enabled by adding this line to your `.screenrc`: **`termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@`**

Comment: @Marius Butuc: http://agentzlerich.blogspot.com/2008/07/using-gnu-screen-with-gnome-terminals.html

Comment: To all thinking of trying this: it's cool at first, but really quirky, and I eventually stopped using it

Answer (score 10):

I'm making great progress in implementing rewrapping in VTE (gnome-terminal etc.). Please see the upstream bug at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336238 , feel free to try my patch if you're a hacker kind. In case of any technical feedback, please comment in that upstream bug, thanks! Hopefully my work will soon end up in mainstream VTE.

Comment: I just want to register my sincere gratitude to you for this work. It's obscene that VTE doesn't rewrap in 2013.

Comment: If this feature could make it to the next Ubuntu version it would be super duper awesome!

Comment: I hope it will make it. It's now included in VTE version 0.35, which will become stable 0.36, part of stable Gnome 3.12.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't make it into ubuntu trusty, but you can upgrade your vte (and gnome-terminal) packages from the gnome3 staging area at https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging/+packages

Answer (score 7):

gnome-terminal can't do it ([upstream bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336238)).

After some experimentation, rxvt-unicode seems like it will work.

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode
```

The reflowing only works after you have enough text to fill up an entire screen's worth, aka once you hit the scrollback buffer.

On a personal note, I find rxvt to be quite ugly, but if reflowing is more important to you, go for it.

Comment: What amazes me is that to this day-  no one has thought to develop a fresh new terminal that isn't based on VTE- that's the reason why most terminal apps for Linux don't reflow.   Just look at Mac OSX's Terminal.app-  it reflows, and is one of the best terminal emulator I have used.

Answer (score 6):

While I unfortunately don't know the answer to this for a normal terminal session, I know how to do it if you're using screen (even if you're using byobu): reattach your screen by using the following:

```
screen -raAd
```

This will scale your screen session as you resize (and also detach any existing running sessions) and is what I always use to bring back a screen session.

Comment: This is cool ... but now I can't scroll up in the terminal .... :(

Comment: For scrolling in `screen`, see [this question](http://superuser.com/q/138748/87525).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it depends on the program that you are using. The terminal itself cannot dynamically wrap text. However, some terminal programs can, e.g. `less`[1].

A work around would be to try to pipe[2] what you want to display through `less`.

[1] http://linuxcommand.org/lts0030.php#less

[2] http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php#pipes

Answer (score 0):

Solution: install **screen** (*sudo apt-get screen*), and launch it in your terminal.

Comment: Better yet, install [byobu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/byobu). It's basically a nice wrapper around `screen`, but one nice feature is that you can have it auto start in all terminals, so you hardly know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Over the last 5+ years I have periodically spent lengthy sessions in *care & feeding* of Linux machines (in far away places).  And, basically, *Gnome Terminal* doesn't quite cut it ..

I have often used *Windows-based* **SecureCRT** and **SecureFX** (SFTP) on both XP and Win7, as well as on Ubuntu (under **Wine**), giving me a much better set of features, including: multi-windows and/or tabs, saved settings, login macros, by-session colorization, much customization, integrated SFTP, and even scripting ..  There were always minor glitches (with Wine, partic. with SFTP), and I often strayed back to *Gnome Terminal* for local tasks on *Ubuntu*.

However, since early this year (in beta), I have had **SecureCRT** (native to *Ubuntu*).  Other than getting tighter integration with Nautilus (or something) for SFTP/SSH file transfer, this has nearly replaced my use of *Gnome Terminal*.

Even new machine setup is better with hassle-free *cut & paste*, full session capture, and saved connection settings.  It has always had superior re-size, re-flow, and character-set handling even over most of the other terminal apps.

I've not tried it, but it has also just been released for *Mac OS X* v1.5 (Intel), or v10.6+.