# How to reflow text in a terminal when you resize?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic line wrapping in the GNOME Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54995/dynamic-line-wrapping-in-the-gnome-terminal)

I'm interested in making my gnome terminal reflow text when resizing the window, i.e., if there is a line break in a long terminal output and I resize the window the text will reflow onto onto line instead of continuing to break at the same spot.

The terminal on Mac OS does this, so it is possible. But perhaps not with `gnome-terminal`.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this or an alternate terminal I can use on Ubuntu that supports this functionality?